# Read options from drop-down list into an array

Tags: vbscript, dropdownbox

I'm trying to write code (in Macro Express Pro) to read all of the options in a drop-down box and set them to an array in this format:

```
;option 1;option 2;option 3;option 4;option 5
```

So far I was able to make it display in a `MsgBox` (just as a test, I don't want the message box in production) ,but not append them to an array. Here is what I'm working with (from the site):

```
<select id="ctl00_cphContent_ddlWorkQueue" class="ddlbox">
    <option value="4449">option 1</option>
    <option value="4370">option 2</option>
    <option value="4371">option 3</option>
    <option value="4372">option 4</option>
    <option value="4373">option 5</option>
</select>
```

From the VBS external script:

```
set OptionChooser = MyIE.Document.GetElementbyid("ctl00_cphContent_ddlWorkQueue")

For Each objOption in OptionChooser.Options
    Msgbox objOption.InnerText
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dynamic array and fill it with the options, then [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) the array:

```
ReDim arr(OptionChooser.Options.Length - 1)
For i = 0 To OptionChooser.Options.Length - 1
  arr(i) = OptionChooser.Options(i).Text
Next
str = Join(arr, ";")

MsgBox str
```

Comment: How do you access the variable outside of the external script? I've tried using str and changing str to Work but only get the results in the MsgBox and not outside of the external script.

Comment: @MichaelAustinKerr: What do you mean by "outside"? Where do you want that value to go?

Comment: Sorry, figured it out. The value ended up being way too big so it wasn't copying over right. I'll try writing it to a text or something then picking it back up from there.